# How can I draw the lines of different colors in openGL-2D?

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to implement the different colors to draw the lines in OpenGL-2D, however the function glColor3f hints cannot two few arguments in function call.And I create the enum to represent the different colors. How can I fix the problem?

Here is my code:

```
#define FREEGLUT_STATIC
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

void display_sub_lines();

//parameters
enum color { black = (0, 0, 0), green = (0, 1, 0), yellow = (1, 1, 0), blue = (0, 0, 1), blue_2 = (0, 1, 1) };
vector<color> colors = { black,green,yellow,blue,blue_2 };
vector<int> x = {1,2,3,4,5};
vector<int> y = {1,2,3,4,5};

//functions
void main(int argc, char** argv) {
glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutInitWindowSize(600, 400);
    glutInitWindowPosition(50, 50);


    glutCreateWindow("Graphics Perimitives");
    glutDisplayFunc(display_sub_lines);
    glutMainLoop();

}

void display_sub_lines() {
    glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


    //TASK 2        
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(-400, 400, -100, 100);


    glLineWidth(1.0);


    for(int index = 0;index<colors.size();index++){

    glColor3f(colors[index]);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex2f(x[index],y[index]);
    glVertex2f(x[index], y[index]);
    glEnd();

}

}
```

Comment: You've been fooled by the [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator). `black = (0, 0, 0)` is just `black = 0`. An `enum` can't take an array of values like that.

Comment: What is "OpenGL-2D"?

Comment: @NicolBolas: AKA OpenGL.xy :)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the enum color to the data structure cause **the black** = (0,0,0) is just **black** = 0.

```
enum color { black = (0, 0, 0), green = (0, 1, 0), yellow = (1, 1, 0), blue = (0, 0, 1), blue_2 = (0, 1, 1) };  

vector<color> colors = { black,green,yellow,blue,blue_2 };
```

The code part of enum can be changed like this:

```
vector<int> color_1 = { 0,0,1,0,0 };
vector<int> color_2 = { 0,1,1,0,1 };
vector<int> color_3 = { 0,0,0,1,1 };
```

And lines should draw like this:

```
   for(int index = 0;index<colors.size();index++){

    glColor3f(color_1[0],color_2[0],color_3[0]);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex2f(x[index],y[index]);
    glVertex2f(x[index], y[index]);
    glEnd();

}
```

Comment: Separating the color components works but is susceptible to errors. There is nothing to strictly enforce that they never become misaligned with each other. Consider using something like `std::vector<std::array<int, 3>>` or something similar instead.